# Can i add two (click and dblclick) events on a single google map marker

Tags: google-maps

can i add two events like click and dblclick on a single google marker.
Help me out of this.

Thanks,
Pradeep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can see the details in [Google Maps JavaScript API V2 Events](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html)

Comment: Hello Muhammad, but i need both the click and dblclick on the same marker and its not working when i do that.

Comment: Actually what i need id when i click on the marker it should perform one action and when i dblclick the marker, another action should be performed.So when i do this the latest(last) event is performed.

Comment: You mean single click, and dbl click works independently not at the same time?

Comment: It means the support is there but you are not able to make it work right. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Marker

Comment: ya in the above example, it uses zoom event on map and click event on the marker but i need dblclick and click on the same marker

Comment: I saw an example you can check that as well,http://monalisa.cern.ch/blog/2007/05/09/how-to-create-your-own-map-using-google-map-api/ and

Comment: ya ill do that but i can edit the question and put the code there ...have a look